# Change zero index in array to 1 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rendering, jsx

I need to list songs from an array in ascending order, but now it's starting from 0 not 1, result:

[songs list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNbof.jpg)

I need to ignore zero and start counting from one. Current result what i achieved is rendered in React JSX syntax. Numbers are rendered by `songs` array `{index}`

**code**:

```
{album.songs && album.songs.map((song, index) => (
   <ul>
     <li>{index}. {song.title} {song.length} </li>
     <hr />
   </ul>
))}
```

So how to render index numbers in array from 1 to n?

Or i can create some new array with numbers and loop trought it?

Comment: Just add {index + 1}.

Comment: {index + 1} works!

Comment: Have you considered using an ordered list `<ol>`? That way you would get the numbering for free.

Comment: Already tried, won't work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li>{index+1}. {song.title} {song.length} </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the current `index` by `1` like the following:

`<li>{index+1}. {song.title} {song.length} </li>`

Answer (score 0):

```
 {index + 1}
```

just increase it by one?

Answer (score 0):

just change `{index}` to `{index+1}`